# Firebase authentication Signup with Phone Number error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase authentication to sign up using phone number. But any sms not being send.

I am getting this error

> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@d5a4a6d

My gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have missed setting up Firebase in your application.

Follow the whole process from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Make sure you have **google-services.json** file in in the module (app-level) directory of your app.

Your root-level (project-level) Gradle file (build.gradle) must have these lines.

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
  // ...

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), add a line to the bottom of the file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

// Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), add the dependency for the core Firebase SDK:

```
dependencies {
 // ...
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

 // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure that you've added
 // Google's Maven repository to your root-level build.gradle file
}
```

Comment: All are in place. Firebase assitant says "connected" and "Dependencies set up correctly",  still getting   `W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@30c04c8`